# Найти самое длинное слово, разделяя строку на слова

Tags: c++, qt

Дана строка S размером не более 100 символов, состоящая только из пробелов и строчных латинских букв. Строка представляет из себя предложение, т.е. несколько слов, состоящих из букв и разделённых между собой пробелами. Нужно найти самое длинное слово. Если слов максимальной длины несколько,выведите то, которое встречается в строке раньше.
Написал код, но он не работает! Спасибо за помощь.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        char S [101] = {};
        cin.getline(S, 101);
        char *ptr = nullptr;
        char *words = nullptr;
        short max = 0;
        /* Вычленяю слова из строки и сравниваю их длину
        с  max, если больше то присваиваю новое значение max и
    копирую слово в  words*/
        ptr = strtok(S, " ");
        while (ptr) {
            short n = strlen(ptr);
            if( max < n){
                max = n;
                words = nullptr;
                strncpy(words, ptr, max);
            }
            ptr = strtok(nullptr, " ");
        }
/*вывожу ответ*/
        cout << words;
        delete ptr;
        delete words;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Намекаю. `std::string str; std::cin >> str;` прочитает ровно одно слово из потока ввода

Comment: Намёк не понял, а как же остальные сравнить?

Comment: Читайте по одному слову, и сохраняйте в переменную самое длинное. Длинна - `str.size()`

Comment: а причем тут Qt?

Comment: Т.е. вывод запустить циклом: while(cin >>str){ if(max<strlen(str)){ max = strlen(str); strncpy(w, str, max);}} Я правильно понял?

Comment: Вот сдались вам эти С строки. Раз уж используете С++, используйте его на полную. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eaf9e70878cf48cf

Comment: Замечательно простой код, но одна тонкость,  мы ещё не дошли до библиотеки <string> поэтому я не мог её воспользоваться и задавал такие вопросы. Спасибо.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, решение не соответствует условию задачи. Надо разобрать имеющуюся строку, а не вводить строки до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет Ctrl-Z.

Comment: @freim, именно поэтому оно в комментарии а не в ответе. Посыл был про использование С-шных строк и функций.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно еще вот так

```
  char str[] = "Особенности 

национальной рыбалки - художественный, комедийный фильм.";

  std::cout << "Разделение строки "" << str << "" на лексемы:n";
  char * pch = strtok (str," ,.-"); // во втором параметре указаны разделитель (пробел, запятая, точка, тире)

  while (pch != NULL)                         // пока есть лексемы
  {
      std::cout << pch  << "n";
      pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот этот код работает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main() {
  string word, w, line;

  getline(cin, line);
  size_t start, end = 0;

  while (end != string::npos && (start = line.find_first_not_of(' ', end)) != string::npos) {
    end = line.find_first_of(' ', start);
    w = line.substr(start, (end != string::npos) ? (end - start) : string::npos);
    if (w.length() > word.length()) word = w;
  }

  cout << word;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Действительно работает, но мне многие элементы ещё не знакомы.

Comment: @Trulimon, повод познакомиться.